# Searching for text/link references on a whole website

Tags: automation

i have a website which is being updated with a new Domain URL, i want to use a fast way of searching the whole website for the old url to find all of the references is there anything such as automation that can help me do this?

Comment: If you're partial to ruby, you could use [`anemone`](https://github.com/chriskite/anemone)

Answer (score 0):

If the old url does not exist anymore maybe you can use a tool to check for dead links, for example deadlinkchecker or brokenlinkcheck.

Another way is to write a script to crawl the site.